# Closed form value for Modified Bessel Function of the second kind at 1

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've come across the following closed-form formulas for the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $K_{\nu}(x)$.

$$K_{1/2}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}} e^{-x} \;,$$ and
$$K_{3/2}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}} e^{-x} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) \;.$$

However, I can't seem to find a closed-form formula anywhere for $K_1(x)$. Does anyone happen to know of such a formula, or perhaps a reference for one? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap4.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K_\nu(x)$ is a special function. Any special function was defined and standardised because it cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. One might say that a special function is it's own closed form.

Sometimes a special functions reduces to function(s) of lower level or to elementary functions for particular values of a parameter. But not for any value of the parameter.

This is the case of the function $K_\nu(x)$ when $\nu=n+\frac{1}{2}$ :
$$K_{1/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}$$
$$K_{3/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$K_{5/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{3}{x}+\frac{3}{x^2}\right)$$
$$K_{7/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}\left(1+\frac{6}{x}+\frac{15}{x^2}+\frac{15}{x^3}\right)$$
etc.

But this is not the case for integer $\nu=n$. For example $K_1(x)$ is it's own closed form.

This kind of behaviour is common for a lot of special functions. For example with the Bessel function of first kind $J_\nu(x)$ :
$$J_{1/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sin(x)$$
$$J_{3/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}e^{-x}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-\cos(x)\right)$$

Other examples with the Incomplete Gamma function $\Gamma(\nu,x)$ and integer $\nu=n>0 $ :
$$\Gamma(1,x)=e^{-x}$$
$$\Gamma(2,x)=e^{-x}(1+x)$$
$$\Gamma(3,x)=e^{-x}(2+2x+x^2)$$

Comment: Does this holds for the modified Bessel functions of the first kind also? Please provide some reference shown why for integer orders $\nu$ the modified Bessel functions of the first/second kind have no closed form in terms of the standard elementary functions.